# Leave one out Cross validation using sklearn (Multiple CSV)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have 52 CSV files in a folder. I want to build a model based on this data. That's why I want to do Leave one out cross-validation on these data. How can I do this using sci-kit learn in python?

I tried from sci kit document and also search many resources.But I didn't found the solution. I have tried this code.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut
path=r'...................\Data\New design process data'
filelist=glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
loo=LeaveOneOut()
for train,test in loo.split(filelist):
   print("%s %s" % (train, test))
```

But it showed errors.

**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

I am new in python as well as sci-kit learn. If anyone can help me, It would be a great convenience.

Comment: `LeaveOneOut` takes a required positional argument `n` that indicates the total number of elements, as per [docs](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html)

Comment: I have also tried "loo=LeaveOneOut(len(filelist))". But it showed "'LeaveOneOut' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: @Lzz0 did you find answer for your problem?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the newer version of the module, which is located in `sklearn.model_selection` instead of `sklearn.cross_validation`. (The `cross_validation` module was depricated in 0.18.) Using this version, you can instantiate the class without the positional argument, and it also does not fail when you try to call split.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2])
loo = LeaveOneOut()  # works without passing an argument
loo.get_n_splits(X)  # returns 2
```